# Multi-Label Image Classification

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I tried myself but couldn't reach the final point that's why posting here, please guide me.

- I am working in multi-label image classification and have slightly
  different scenarios. Actually I am confused, how we will map labels and their attribute with Id etc So we can use for training and testing.
- Here is code on which I am working

  ```
  import os
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  from keras.utils import to_categorical
  from collections import Counter
  from keras.callbacks import Callback
  from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
  from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

  from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
  from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
  from matplotlib import pyplot
  from tensorflow.keras import backend

  def create_tag_mapping(mapping_csv):
      labels = set()
      for i in range(len(mapping_csv)):
          tags = mapping_csv['Labels'][i].split(' ')
          labels.update(tags)
      labels = list(labels)
      labels.sort()
      labels_map = {labels[i]:i for i in range(len(labels))}
      inv_labels_map = {i:labels[i] for i in range(len(labels))}
      return labels_map, inv_labels_map

  # create a mapping of filename to tags
  def create_file_mapping(mapping_csv):
      mapping = dict()
      for i in range(len(mapping_csv)):
          name, tags = mapping_csv['Id'][i], mapping_csv['Labels'][i]
          mapping[name] = tags.split(' ')
      return mapping

  # create a one hot encoding for one list of tags
  def one_hot_encode(tags, mapping):
      # create empty vector
      encoding = np.zeros(len(mapping), dtype='uint8')
      # mark 1 for each tag in the vector
      for tag in tags:
          encoding[mapping[tag]] = 1
      return encoding

  def load_dataset(path, file_mapping, tag_mapping):
      photos, targets = list(), list()
      # enumerate files in the directory
      for filename in os.listdir(path):
          # load image
          photo = load_img(path + filename, target_size=(760,415))
          # convert to numpy array
          photo = img_to_array(photo, dtype='uint8')
          # get tags
          tags = file_mapping[filename[:-4]]
          # one hot encode tags
          target = one_hot_encode(tags, tag_mapping)
          # store
          photos.append(photo)
          targets.append(target)
      X = np.asarray(photos, dtype='uint8')
      y = np.asarray(targets, dtype='uint8')
      return X, y

  trainingLabels = 'labels.csv'
  # load the mapping file
  mapping_csv = pd.read_csv(trainingLabels)


  # create a mapping of tags to integers
  tag_mapping, _ = create_tag_mapping(mapping_csv)

  # create a mapping of filenames to tag lists
  file_mapping = create_file_mapping(mapping_csv)


  # load the png images
  folder = 'dataset/'

  X, y = load_dataset(folder, file_mapping, tag_mapping)
  print(X.shape, y.shape)

  trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
  print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape, testX.shape, testY.shape)

  img_x,img_y=760,415
  trainX=trainX.reshape(trainX.shape[0], img_x,img_y,3)
  testX=testX.reshape(testX.shape[0], img_x,img_y,3)

  trainX=trainX.astype('float32')
  testX=testX.astype('float32')

  trainX /= 255
  testX /=255

  trainY=to_categorical(trainY,3)
  testY=to_categorical(testY,3)
  print(trainX.shape)
  print(trainY.shape)

  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(img_x, img_y,3)))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2,2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  history=model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=2, epochs=5, verbose=1)
  plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
  plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
  plt.title('Accuracy and loss')
  plt.xlabel('epoch')
  plt.ylabel('accuracy/loss')
  plt.legend(['Accuracy','loss'],loc='upper left')
  plt.show()

  score=model.evaluate(testX,testY,verbose=0)
  print('test loss',score[0])
  print('test accuracy',score[1])
  ```

> I have attached an image file[image: Explaination], that will give a clear picture of my problem.

Because If we followed these

1. https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-satellite-photos-of-the-amazon-rainforest/
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff
3. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/

etc.
They have multi labels against each image but in my case, I have multilabel plus their attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the above discussion. Here is the solution for the above problem.
As I mentioned we have a total of 5 labels and each label have further three tags like (L, M, H) We can perform encoding in this way

```
# create a one hot encoding for one list of tags
def custom_encode(tags, mapping):
    # create empty vector
    encoding=[]
    for tag in tags:
        if tag == 'L':
            encoding.append([1,0,0])
        elif tag == 'M':
            encoding.append([0,1,0])
        else:
            encoding.append([0,0,1])
    return encoding
```

So encoded y-vector will look like

```
**Labels     Tags             Encoded Tags** 
Label1 ----> [L,L,L,M,H] ---> [ [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]
Label2 ----> [L,H,L,M,H] ---> [ [1,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]
Label3 ----> [L,M,L,M,H] ---> [ [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]
Label4 ----> [M,M,L,M,H] ---> [ [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]
Label5 ----> [M,L,L,M,H] ---> [ [0,1,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1] ]
```

The final layer will be like

```
 model.add(Dense(15)) #because we have total 5 labels and each has 3 tags so 15 neurons will be on final layer
 model.add(Reshape((5,3))) # each 5 have further 3 tags we need to reshape it
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to predict if '*L*', '*M*' and '*H*', you are using an incorrect loss function. You should use `binary_crossentropy`. The shape of your targets will be *batch* × 3 in this case.

- [`categorical_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/categorical_crossentropy) assumes the output is a categorical distribution: a vector of values that sum up to one. In other words, you have multiple possibilities, but only of them can be the correct one.
- [`binary_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/binary_crossentropy) assumes that every number from the output vector is a (conditionally) independent binary distribution, so each number is between 0 and 1, but they do not necessarily sum up to one, because it can very well happen that all of them true.

If your goal is to predict for each label1, ..., label6 the value, then you should model a categorical distribution for each of the labels. You have six labels, each of them has 3 values, you thus need 18 numbers (logits). The shape of your targets will be *batch* × 6 × 3 in this case.

```py
model.add(Dense(18, activation='none'))
```

Because you don't want a single distribution over 18 values, but over 6 × 3 values, you need to reshape the logits first:

```py
model.add(Reshape((6, 3))
model.add(Softmax())
```

Comment: #Jindřich thank you for answer
How we can perform mapping, like before training we map Id with labels. So we can feed them for training.
Like you mentioned categorical distribution for each of the labels

Comment: I would do it in numpy as you load the data. For each row, you can either do a vector of shape (6,) and add indices like L=0, M=1, H=2 and then use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`; or do np.zeros((6,3)) and then manually assign ones to respective places and use `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thank you
Can you please share a link regarding that
I didn't get your point 'you can either do a vector of shape (6,) and add indices like L=0, M=1, H=2 '
actually I am a beginner in ML, DL, and python that's why need more explanation
will very thankful

Comment: I meant: your six labels, e.g., H L M L H H M=> [2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1] in the sparse case, but [[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,1,0]] in the non-sparse case.

Comment: Ok got it
Please also let me know where I will place it
 before the final layer?
"Because you don't want a single distribution over 6 values, but over 6 × 3 values, you need to reshape the logits first:

model.add(Reshape((6, 3))
model.add(Softmax())"

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant 18 values. Put the three layers from my snippet instead of your original sigmoid layer.

Comment: Jindrich, please guide m here
I have encoded my labels in such way H L M L H H M=> [[0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,1,0]]
and used your above mentioned code snippet
in this case our loss function will be 'categorical_crossentropy'?
am I right? if not then please guide me

Comment: Sorry, I mean 'binary_crossentropy'